# Mockito matchers exception 0 matchers expected, 3 !! all recorded records are matchers

Tags: java, mockito

I have a Mockito when with matchers

```
Mockito.when(aRepository.searchForList(
    Mockito.any(LocalDateTime.class),
    Mockito.anyLong(), 
    Mockito.anyBoolean()
)).thenReturn(mockedSearchForList);
```

so after i run tests, have this exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

Described exception may occur if I mix matchers and real values, which is not my case.

Comment: What's the signature of `aRepository.searchForList` ? Is this method overloaded?

Comment: List<ServiceListResult> searchForList(LocalDateTime now, long envId, boolean showInactives);

Comment: This should work. So, there are several things that can go wrong. I.e. the exception can come from other code. This method can be overridden. This might be a Mockito bug too. Btw, which version of Mockito are you using?

Comment: I use mockito 1.10.19 , @TamasRev

Comment: That's quite recent. Can you reproduce it with 1.9? 2.0?

Comment: The problem is on my service layer i use the same thing and it works,
but not work in my controller layer test.
the différence between this two module is in the controller test my aRepository is mocked with Primary and qualifier annotation

Comment: Can you verify that searchForList is public and non-final, and possibly paste the whole test method so we can see the call's surroundings?

Comment: yes it's public and not final

Comment: I solve this issue, by disabling Hibernate Aspect.
it's not a problem of mockito.
when aspect throw an exception, mockito throw matcher exception

Comment: @Unesfs You should probably rewrite the question to inculde the information about the Hibernate aspects, and then answer and accept this question yourself, or delete this question. It might be useful to to others. Or, the question should probably be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved in the comments:

> I solve this issue, by disabling Hibernate Aspect. it's not a problem of mockito. when aspect throw an exception, mockito throw matcher exception